# Apache-POI: "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

I want to use Apache POI to read and write Excel files in Java.
I am using Maven for the dependencies, but when importing I get the error: `Cannot resolve symbol usermodel` for example.

These are my imports:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

This is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Boekhouding</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-3.17</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\poi-3.17.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\poi-ooxml-3.17.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change your dependencies with that.
This is more suitable and enough for solution.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using maven. But this answer cannot be correct at all.  1. It suggests using pretty old `apache poi` versions instead using [the latest stable release](https://poi.apache.org/download.html). 2. It suggests mixing versions 3.7 and 3.9. But this is [not supported](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204) at all.

Comment: actually it is working right now but you totally right. i will update answer.

Comment: Can you please try your suggestions? You **willI** need `poi-ooxml` additional to `poi` because `poi-ooxml` is needed for `XSSF`-Excel XLSX and is not included in `poi`. But you need all of those from **one** version only, currently from version 3.17.

Comment: Now 3.17 version doesn't solve the problem select the version **4.0.1** for both `poi` and `poi-ooxml`